# How to unset N right-most set bits

Tags: bit-manipulation, intrinsics, integer-arithmetic

There is a relatively well-known trick for unsetting a single right-most bit:

```
y = x & (x - 1) // 0b001011100 & 0b001011011 = 0b001011000 :)
```

I'm finding myself with a tight loop to clear n right-most bits, but is there a simpler algebraic trick?

Assume relatively large n (n has to be <64 for 64bit integers, but it's often on the order of 20-30).

```
// x = 0b001011100 n=2
for (auto i=0; i<n; i++) x &= x - 1;
// x = 0b001010000
```

I've thumbed my TAOCP Vol4a few times, but can't find any inspiration.

Maybe there is some hardware support for it?

Comment: Any particular ISA you care about for HW support?  I think x86 `pext` / `pdep` to make the set bits contiguous can work, to allow clearing them with AND.

Comment: Interesting - I looked at `pext`/`pdep` briefly, but it appears I'd need to compute the mask in advance, right? I can't guarantee that the n bits are continuous in the input variable.

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but I think `pext(a,a)` will pack the bits at the bottom: the desired mask of which bits to select *is* the input number, because you want all the set bits and none of the clear bits.

Comment: Random idea: mask off some arbitrary number of bits (say `(64+n)/2`), use popcount to see how many you cleared, and binary search until you get it right.  Should take at most 6 iterations, but the unpredictable branches might be a killer, unless there is a clever branchless approach.

Comment: That's a good idea on hardware that supports `popcount` but not `pdep`. I'm really happy (myself) with @PeterCordes answer - it works, and I was actually able to optimize more places once I read BMI2 manual; I'm still curious if there is a way to accelerate it on a more restricted hardware! I'll accept it in a few days, in the meantime. lets solicit non-BMI2 alternatives!

Comment: @NateEldredge: In general you can make binary search branchless.  When searching memory you often don't want to (speculative execution trigger HW prefetch, and cache misses cost more than branch misses).  But here yeah you could just have something that compiles to `cmov` with the only branch being the  while `popcnt(result) == popcnt(input)-n` loop branch.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Added that idea to my answer as a fallback.  Since popcount doesn't care *where* the bits are, it's often more efficient to shift the bit than to create a mask and then AND it, but the basic idea is solid and may be faster than PDEP on AMD.

Comment: related: [Efficiently finding the position of the k'th set bit in a bitset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28485961/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Intel x86 CPUs with BMI2, [`pext`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pext) and [`pdep`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pdep) are fast.  **AMD before Zen3 has very slow microcoded PEXT/PDEP** (https://uops.info/) so be careful with this; other options might be faster on AMD, maybe even `blsi` in a loop, or better a binary-search on popcount (see below).
Only Intel has dedicated hardware execution units for the mask-controlled pack/unpack that pext/pdep do, making it constant-time: 1 uop, 3 cycle latency, can only run on port 1.

I'm not aware of other ISAs having a similar bit-packing hardware operation.

(For the much simpler problem of simply the low `n` bits, `x & (-1ULL<<n)` if you don't need to handle n=64.  Otherwise maybe `bzhi` against `-1` / `andn`.)

---

**`pdep` basics**: `pdep(-1ULL, a) == a`.  Taking the low popcnt(a) bits from the first operand, and depositing them at the places where `a` has set bits, will give you `a` back again.

But if, instead of all-ones, your source of bits has the low N bits cleared, the first N set bits in `a` will grab a 0 instead of 1.  This is exactly what you want.

```
uint64_t unset_first_n_bits_bmi2(uint64_t a, int n){
    return _pdep_u64(-1ULL << n, a);
}
```

`-1ULL << n` works for n=0..63 in C.  x86 asm scalar shift instructions mask their count (effectively `&63`), so that's *probably* what will happen for the C undefined-behaviour of a larger `n`.  If you care, use `n&63` in the source so the behaviour is well-defined in C, and it can still compile to a shift instruction that uses the count directly.

[On Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/fd766M) with a simple looping reference implementation, showing that they produce the same result for a sample input `a` and `n`.

GCC and clang both compile it the obvious way, as written:

```
# GCC10.2 -O3 -march=skylake
unset_first_n_bits_bmi2(unsigned long, int):
        mov     rax, -1
        shlx    rax, rax, rsi
        pdep    rax, rax, rdi
        ret
```

(SHLX is single-uop, 1 cycle latency, unlike legacy variable-count shifts that update FLAGS... except if CL=0.  uops.info reports Alder Lake has 3 cycle latency for `shlx`, but that doesn't make much sense and is inconsistent with InstLatx64 measurements so [I'm pretty sure SHLX/SHRX latency is still 1 cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77705346/compiler-flags-of-gcc-clang-to-generate-bextr-instruction-of-ia32s-bmi1/77705726#77705726).)

So this has 3 cycle latency from `a`->output (just pdep)
and 4 cycle latency from `n`->output (shlx, pdep).

And is only 3 uops for the front-end.

---

A semi-related BMI2 trick:

**`pext(a,a)` will pack the bits at the bottom**, like `(1ULL<<popcnt(a)) - 1` but without overflow if all bits are set.

Clearing the low N bits of that with an AND mask, and expanding with `pdep` would work.  But that's an overcomplicated expensive way to create a source of bits with enough ones above N zeros, which is all that actually matters for pdep.  Thanks to @harold for spotting this in the first version of this answer.

---

### Without fast PDEP: perhaps binary search for the right popcount

@Nate's suggestion of a **binary search for how many low bits to clear** is probably a good alternative to pdep.

Stop when `popcount(x>>c) == popcount(x) - N` to find out how many low bits to clear, preferably with branchless updating of `c`.  (e.g. `c = foo ? a : b` often compiles to cmov).

Once you're done searching, `x & (-1ULL<<c)` uses that count, or just `tmp << c` to shift back the `x>>c` result you already have.  Using right-shift directly is cheaper than generating a new mask and using it every iteration.

High-performance popcount is relatively widely available on modern CPUs.  (Although *not* baseline for x86-64; you still need to compile with `-mpopcnt` or `-march=native`).

Tuning this could involve choosing a likely starting-point, and perhaps using a max initial step size instead of pure binary search.  Getting some instruction-level parallelism out of trying some initial guesses could perhaps help shorten the latency bottleneck.

Comment: Couldn't this be done with `pdep(-1ULL << n, a)`?

Comment: @harold: Updated, thanks.  I was thinking of the problem like AVX512 `vpcompressd` where each input element has an identity, but a 1 bit is just a 1 bit, and doesn't have to come from the original input.