# AVX512 - How to move all set bits to the right?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, simd, intrinsics, avx512

How can I move all set bits of mask register to right? (To the bottom, least-significant position).

For example:

```c
__mmask16 mask = _mm512_cmpeq_epi32_mask(vload, vlimit); // mask = 1101110111011101
```

If we move all set bits to the right, we will get: `1101110111011101 -> 0000111111111111`

How can I achieve this efficiently?

Below you can see how I tried to get the same result, but it's inefficient:

```c
__mmask16 mask = 56797;
// mask: 1101110111011101
__m512i vbrdcast = _mm512_maskz_broadcastd_epi32(mask, _mm_set1_epi32(~0));
// vbrdcast: -1 0 -1 -1 -1 0 -1 -1 -1 0 -1 -1 -1 0 -1 -1
__m512i vcompress = _mm512_maskz_compress_epi32(mask, vbrdcast);
// vcompress:-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 
__mmask16 right_packed_mask =   _mm512_movepi32_mask(vcompress);   
// right_packed_mask: 0000111111111111
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you want result as a vector or mask? Something like this could work: `(1 << __builtin_popcount(_cvtmask16_u32(mask))) - 1` (count how many bits are set and then create a mask)

Comment: I want the result as a mask. `mask = ( 1 << bit_count ( .. ) ) -1` works fine. Thank you! I was wondering if there is another way to do this without scalar code.

Comment: In fact, your solution is efficient than mine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**BMI2 `pext` is the scalar bitwise equivalent of `v[p]compressd/q/ps/pd`.**
Use it on your mask value to left-pack them to the bottom of the value.

```
  mask = _pext_u32(-1U, mask);    // or _pext_u64(-1ULL, mask64)  for __mmask64
// costs 3 asm instructions (kmov + pext + kmov) if you need to use the result as a mask
// not including putting -1 in a register.
```

Implicit conversion between __mmask16 (aka uint16_t in GCC) and uint32_t works.
Use `_cvtu32_mask16` and `_cvtu32_mask16` to make the KMOVW explicit if you like.

See [How to unset N right-most set bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65817459/how-to-unset-n-right-most-set-bits) for more about using pext/pdep in ways like this.

**All current CPUs with AVX-512 also have fast BMI2 `pext` (including Xeon Phi)**, same performance as popcnt.  AMD had slow `pext` until Zen 3, but if/when AMD ever introduces an AVX-512 CPU it should have fast `pext`/`pdep`.

For earlier AMD without AVX512, you might want `(1ULL << __builtin_popcount(mask)) - 1`, but be careful of overflow if all bits are set.  `1ULL << 64` is undefined behaviour, and likely to produce `1` not `0` when compiled for x86-64.

---

If you were going to use `vpcompressd`, note that the source vector can simply be all-ones `_mm512_set1_epi32(-1)`; compress doesn't care about elements where the mask was zero, they don't need to already be zero.

(It doesn't matter *which* `-1`s you pack; once you're working with boolean values, there's no difference between a `true` that came from your original bitmask vs. a constant `true` that was just sitting there which you generated more cheaply, without a dependency on your input mask.  Same reasoning applies for `pext`, why you can use `-1U` as the source data instead of a `pdep`.  i.e. a `-1` or set bit doesn't have an identity; it's the same as any other `-1` or set bit).

So let's try both ways and see how good/bad the asm is.

```
inline
__mmask16 leftpack_k(__mmask16 mask){
    return _pdep_u32(-1U, mask);
}

inline
__mmask16 leftpack_comp(__mmask16 mask) {
    __m512i v = _mm512_maskz_compress_epi32(mask, _mm512_set1_epi32(-1));
    return _mm512_movepi32_mask(v);
}
```

Looking at stand-alone versions of these isn't useful because `__mmask16` is a typedef for `unsigned short`, and is thus passed/returned in integer registers, not `k` registers.  That makes the `pext` version look very good, of course, but we want to see how it inlines into a case where we generate and use the mask with AVX-512 intrinsics.

```
// not a useful function, just something that compiles to asm in an obvious way
void use_leftpack_compress(void *dst, __m512i v){
    __mmask16 m = _mm512_test_epi32_mask(v,v);
    m = leftpack_comp(m);
    _mm512_mask_storeu_epi32(dst, m, v);
}
```

Commenting out the `m = pack(m)`, this is just a simple 2 instructions that generate and then use a mask.

```
use_mask_nocompress(void*, long long __vector(8)):
        vptestmd        k1, zmm0, zmm0
        vmovdqu32       ZMMWORD PTR [rdi]{k1}, zmm0
        ret
```

So any extra instructions will be due to left-packing (compressing) the mask.  GCC and clang make the same asm as each other, differing only in clang avoiding `kmovw` in favour of always `kmovd`.  [**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrRDbSV9ABk8tTADlnACNMYi4ADlIAB1QhQnNaO0cXN2jY%2BLofP0CnELDOSONMUwSGAmZiAiTnV3cikroyioIsgODQiKNyyuqUuu6W3zbcjoKASiNUB2JkDikdAGZfZEcsAGpNBZshAnx6ADoETexNGQBBReXVzA2tvCcnXwJiX0Pj04vzgH0vh%2BYhADWnAAbGt2FQCFFmMgAV8ARAfn9ASC1k5/gCxpoAOz6c5rfFrYiYAjTWhrL5RLBRL4OBbaCAAWk4AlIqPRmIWuIuWIAIh8PgA3VB4dBrBwiL7gyHQ2HwoUitYAKnQO1ZiIArJxtHg1gLMTiPgTyb80cjQU5bjzyQ9NdovgRMDsvpgong6b90RABaQ9ZsuUaLZsrVKoTC4RAnBz/QSTbaPYCvjsSJgHM7XXSICqCKynKzfZz%2Bbz%2Bd8TeiUSGZV80E4ogjS2a2YCxhsDXiY79bTqBZbrU446aAQAvKuoGtEoRCNNu%2BkDtU2rWJ4mcKcZpljKOGgkAei3RJJxDJsYXDqdLun8blPo3bfxe9Jvf7qAFZ/dA691%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%2BmaeGNp2ZpUZGdHtAmWTplmLh%2BMEuzyvEqRxHCYEGWBbg1mAZBkDWKL9iuiBcEIEgNhMja1jsGswtCBWFk4ZtJL0AxlPs9TNPVGR9hkYFzc4LEsWBdVNe063rKkWzSCcEBjdIES5FIHmnJctyDdILzfNCwLyEoEOOhWLatRkVyqDi0JEuS8q0toTLOty0d8voYrStqzAquAGryrq368EalKWrajqpBy7req9/rBuGjA5i98bXdrviFvoJg2A4ebpuWiQUqUdxVHUFAdsMJuDogI6ToSc7Luu27kHunlHue173s%2BrVvpMP7LGsanQe8IYIdGNJYYSU%2Bkb%2B%2BnIZprHiYGU%2BidKAZH6v2m8eSYGuh0wvuTLWkxWYDw5lIISHsUo8z5gLIWawo7qAltoU2ps1gy3wExDWSsVYBXVosJmytp76w8hMBAmBmBYDCPPR2ztXbu09g5KQvtXLuTUhMI2JszYWytjbO2DteoLC5l7H2/tyGO20KIlhZDOE%2BkTgkLSQA)

```
# GCC10.3 -O3 -march=skylake-avx512
use_leftpack_k(void*, long long __vector(8)):
        vptestmd        k0, zmm0, zmm0
        mov     eax, -1                        # could be hoisted out of a loop
        kmovd   edx, k0
        pdep    eax, eax, edx
        kmovw   k1, eax
        vmovdqu32       ZMMWORD PTR [rdi]{k1}, zmm0
        ret
```

```
use_leftpack_compress(void*, long long __vector(8)):
        vptestmd        k1, zmm0, zmm0
        vpternlogd      zmm2, zmm2, zmm2, 0xFF   # set1(-1)  could be hoisted out of a loop
        vpcompressd     zmm1{k1}{z}, zmm2
        vpmovd2m        k1, zmm1
        vmovdqu32       ZMMWORD PTR [rdi]{k1}, zmm0
        ret
```

So the non-hoistable parts are

- `kmov r,k` (port 0) / `pext` (port 1) / `kmov k,r` (port 5) = 3 uops, one for each execution port.  (Including port 1, which has its vector ALUs shut down while 512-bit uops are in flight).  The kmov/kmov round trip has [4 cycle latency on SKX](https://uops.info/html-lat/SKX/KMOVW_R32_K-Measurements.html#lat2-%3E1), and `pext` is 3 cycle latency, for a **total of 7 cycle latency**.
- `vpcompressd zmm{k}{z}, z` (2 p5) / `vpmovd2m` (port 0) = 3 uops, two for port 5.  `vpmovd2m` has [3 cycle latency on SKX](https://uops.info/html-lat/SKX/VPMOVD2M_K_ZMM-Measurements.html) / ICL, and `vpcompressd`-zeroing-into-zmm has 6 cycle from the k input to the zmm output ([SKX](https://uops.info/html-lat/SKX/VPCOMPRESSD_Z_ZMM_K_ZMM-Measurements.html#lat2-%3E1) and ICL).  So a **total of 9 cycle latency**, and worse port distribution for the uops.

Also, the hoistable part is generally worse (`vpternlogd` is longer and competes for fewer ports than `mov r32, imm32`), unless your function already needs an all-ones vector for something but not an all-ones register.

**Conclusion: the BMI2 `pext` way is not worse in any way, and better in several**.  (Unless surrounding code *heavily* bottlenecked on port 1 uops, which is very unlikely if using 512-bit vectors because in that case it can only be running scalar integer uops like 3-cycle LEA, IMUL, LZCNT, and of course simple 1-cycle integer stuff like add/sub/and/or).