# AVX512 - Left packing elements by index using mask

Tags: c++, simd, intrinsics, avx2, avx512

In short, I am trying to compress(left pack) 64-bit integers by index. Neither *scatter* nor *compress* intrinsics solves this problem directly.

Suppose you have eight 64-bit integers in `a` and want to *left pack* those elements at addresses starting at `base_addr` by the `index` subject to mask `k`.

```c
int64_t* dst; // memory to store the result
__m512i a = _mm512_loadu_si512 ( arr ); // load data from memory into a
__mmask8 k = _mm512_cmpgt_epi64_mask ( a, _mm512_set1_epi64(6) ); // compare for greater-than
__m512i index = _mm512_set_epi64 ( 14, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0 ); // index vector
_mm512_mask_compressstoreu_epi64_by_index ( dst, k, index, a ); // How can I implement this function efficiently?
```

So, _mm512_mask_compressstoreu_epi64_by_index function should *compress* 64-bit integers from `a` into memory `dst` using `index`. The writemask `k` stores the element,  which is active in `a`, to memory.

The result of this function will looks like:

`dst = [10, 0, 7, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0 ...]`.

The elements 10, 7 and 9 are stored after an index 0, 2 and 4 accordingly.

I've tried `_mm512_mask_compressstoreu_epi64` and `_mm512_mask_i64scatter_epi64` intrinsics, but these instructions save the elements differently. They will give you following results:

`_mm512_mask_compressstoreu_epi64( dst, k, a )` produces: `dst = [ 10, 7, 9 , ... ]`

`_mm512_mask_i64scatter_epi64 ( dst, k, index, a, 8 )` produces: `dst = [ 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, ...]`

What I want is `_mm512_mask_compressstoreu_epi64_by_index( dst, k, index, a )` which results `dst = [10, 0, 7, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0 ...]`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I would suggest using an unambiguous type like `int32_t` or `int64_t` instead of `long`, which could be either. The drawing suggests that the question assumes that `long` is a 64-bit type.

Comment: I have updated.

Comment: _mm512_maskz_compress_epi64 and then _mm512_permutexvar_epi64?

Comment: Is the `index` always a simple 0,2,4,6,... every other element?  SIMD shuffles (at least on x86) really don't support destination-index easily at all, but if your shuffle pattern is that simple, it sounds like you just want to zero-extend your 64-bit integers to 128-bit.  You can do that with a fixed shuffle.  If you still need a masked store, you'd have to double your mask bits somehow, so it has twice as many bits, because unfortunately there isn't a `vmovdqu128` that can mask at 128-bit granularity.

Comment: Probably not optimal, but could you handle the general case by using maskz_compress on the data with that mask, then use [AVX512 - How to move all set bits to the right?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67256047) and use a scatter with that left-packed mask and left-packed data, and the vector of indices.  That might be a useful way to describe what you're trying to do.  It took me a long time to understand what you wanted when I first read this, since most of your examples were of things you didn't want.

Comment: Your illustrations are all in little-endian (i.e., your mask would be `0x92`)?

Comment: @chtz I tried it and I just get the result in a different order

Comment: @stepan Good inspiration!

Comment: @PeterCordes 
reply for "Is the index always a simple 0,2,4,6,... every other element? " - No. It could be any number. 
reply for "Probably not optimal, but could you handle the ..." - Yes. It's really inefficient.

Comment: @him I was actually asking for clarification ... Anyhow, you may be better by simply writing a small non-SIMD loop for this (and hope that the branch-predictor does not get messed up). Maybe if you show the main-loop (or better a [mre]) how you want to use this, someone finds a clever alternative.

Comment: "really inefficient"?  1x `vpcompressq` + kmov/pext/kmov + scatter might still be better than scalar, especially if most of the mask bits are set.  (I think scatter costs about the same regardless of how many mask bits are set). If the index vector can be anything, then obviously you can't just use a shuffle; you might need to write your data outside a single 64-byte chunk.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ok. I'll try it.

Comment: @PeterCordes I was under the impressive that `vpscatter` / `vpgather` actually issued a unique load/store for each corresponding entry so would expect smaller mask to have better performance? Also beware of fault suppression on the mask. If you can make the indices you are not writing to 0 (or some value that won't make the destination cross a page) as fault suppression will decrease performance by 1-2 orders of magnitude.

Comment: @Noah: Fewer mask bits set doesn't stop the masked-scalar-load (or store) from being issued into the back-end, and probably not even to dispatch to an execution unit much more efficiently.  It may avoid the possibility of cache misses for those elements, so faster in that sense, but probably not faster than an all-bits-set mask that got L1d hits in every access.  (Which is what we normally think of as "the performance" from measurements like uops.info).  But yeah, picking some safe location for all the masked elements is probably helpful.

Comment: @PeterCordes note I was wrong about the perf of fault suppression. Its just that if address + VEC_SIZE crosses a page but mask prevents, CPU will still check second page in TLB but if mask doesn't include a load from second page it wont update the TLB. So unless there is a TLB miss there is not significant extra cost AFAICT (my issue is my benchmarks ended up looping on the page cross case with TLB miss so I was essentially benchmarking throughput of TLB miss which is low).